# Convert nested dictionary to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a particular case where I want to create a csv using the inner values of a nested dictionary as the keys and the inner keys as the header. The 'healthy' key can contain more subkeys other than 'height' and 'weight', but the 'unhealthy' will either ever contain None or a string of values.
My current dictionary looks like this:

```
{0: {'healthy': {'height': 160,
                 'weight': 180},
    'unhealthy': None},
 1: {'healthy': {'height': 170,
                'weight': 250},
    'unhealthy': 'alcohol, smoking, overweight'}
}
```

How would I convert this to this csv:

```
+------+--------+----------------------------+
|height|  weight|                   unhealthy|
+------+--------+----------------------------+
|160   |     180|                            |
+------+--------+----------------------------+
|170   |     250|alcohol, smoking, overweight|
+------+--------+----------------------------+
```

Is there anyway of not hardcoding this and doing this without Pandas and saving it to a location?

Comment: Please share what you have attempted and the outcome, including source code and errors.

Comment: @learningtoprogram123 If you find a solution here, please accept the answer so that people can see what answer help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `D` being your dictionary you can pass `D.values()` to [`pandas.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and rename the columns if needed.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> print(pd.json_normalize(D.values()).to_markdown(tablefmt='psql'))
+╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌+
|    | unhealthy                    |   healthy.height |   healthy.weight |
|╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌|
|  0 |                              |              160 |              180 |
|  1 | alcohol, smoking, overweight |              170 |              250 |
+╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌+╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌+
```

Answer (score 1):

So this may be very dumb way to do this, but if your dictionary has this structure and you don't mind about hardcoding the actual values, this might be the way

```
import csv

dictionary = {0: {'healthy': {'height': 160,
                              'weight': 180},
                  'unhealthy': None},
              1: {'healthy': {'height': 170,
                              'weight': 250},
                  'unhealthy': 'alcohol, smoking, overweight'}
              }

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['height', 'weight', 'unhealthy'])
    writer.writerows([
        [value['healthy']['height'],
         value['healthy']['weight'],
         value['unhealthy']
         ] for key, value in dictionary.items()])
```

So the point is you just create an array of `[<height>, <weight>, <unhealthy>]` arrays and write it to csv file using python's builtin module's `csv.writer.writerows()`

Comment: I like this 'cause it's not Pandas, but I think the list comprehension is hard to comprehend/hides meaning. How would you feel about editing to show an explicit loop?

Answer (score 0):

I used `pandas` to deal with the value and to save it as a `csv` file.

1. I loaded the `json` format data as a dataframe.
2. By transposing the data, I got 'unhealty' columne
3. By using `json_normalize()`, I parsed the nested dictionary data, 'healthy' and generated two columns into 'height' and 'weight'
4. concat the 'healthy' and 'height', 'weight' columns
5. saved the dataframe as a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

val = {
    0: {'healthy': {'height': 160, 'weight': 180},
        'unhealthy': None},
    1: {'healthy': {'height': 170, 'weight': 250},
        'unhealthy': 'alcohol, smoking, overweight'}
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(val)
df = df.transpose()
df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df['healthy'], max_level=1), df['unhealthy']], axis=1)
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False) # A csv file generated.
```

This is the csv file I generated (I opend it using MS Excel).
[image: This is the csv file]